# Confusion about HotSpot JVM JIT

Tags: java, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

For example,a loop with 10000 times in a method.When it runs 1000 times, the backedge_counter triggers the `JIT` compilation. And the interpreter continue executing. When it loops **4000** times, the `JIT` compilation completes.

My question is, how does the **remainder 6000** times be executed, by interpreter, or execute native code?Or the native code is not executed until this method is invoked next time?
And what happens when this method is invoked next time?

Comment: Why wouldn't it execute natively? Isn't that the point of JIT compilation?

Comment: +1 It's an interesting, non-trivial question that doen't deserve the downvotes IMHO. Is the Java HotSpot compiler able to change a currently-running method invocation from interpreted to compiled code? The question's wording isn't perfect as JIT and HotSpot are subtly different approaches, but the text made clear that HotSpot is meant.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff If it wasn't able to change a method what exactly would the point of it be? Maybe it lets the current invocation complete, but surely not the next 5999 times. The question is asinine.

Comment: Of course HotSpot is able the exchange methods from interpreted to native while this method is not executing. That's for granted. Is that also possible while the method is in the middle of its execution?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff That's not the question that was asked. The question was explicitly about the remaining 6,000 invocations.

Comment: @ EJP,Sorry for my unclear expression. I modify it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about HotSpot JVM, the answer is the remaining interations will be executed in **compiled** code.

HotSpot JVM has a technique known as 'on-stack replacement' to switch from interpreter to compiled code while the method is running.

http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/HotSpotGlossary.html

> **on-stack replacement**
>   Also known as 'OSR'. The process of converting an
>   interpreted (or less optimized) stack frame into a compiled (or more
>   optimized) stack frame. This happens when the interpreter discovers
>   that a method is looping, requests the compiler to generate a special
>   nmethod with an entry point somewhere in the loop (specifically, at a
>   backward branch), and transfers control to that nmethod. A rough
>   inverse to deoptimization.

If you run JVM with `-XX:+PrintCompilation` flag, OSR compilations will be marked by `%` sign:

```
    274   27       3       java.lang.String::lastIndexOf (52 bytes)
    275   29       3       java.lang.String::startsWith (72 bytes)
    275   28       3       java.lang.String::startsWith (7 bytes)
    275   30       3       java.util.Arrays::copyOf (19 bytes)
    276   32       4       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (29 bytes)
    276   31  s    3       java.lang.StringBuffer::append (13 bytes)
    283   33 %     3       LoopTest::myLongLoop @ 13 (43 bytes)
             ^                                    ^
            OSR                            bytecode index of OSR entry
```

**UPDATE**

Typically after OSR compilation a regular compilation is also queued, so that the next time the method is called, it will start running directly in compiled mode.

```
    187   32 %     3       LoopTest::myLongLoop @ 13 (43 bytes)
    187   33       3       LoopTest::myLongLoop (43 bytes)
```

However, if a regular compilation is not complete by the time the method is called again, the method will start running in interpreter, and then will switch to OSR entry inside a loop.

Comment: But what happens when this method is invoked next time?

Comment: Your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Let's restate the question:

Is the Java HotSpot compiler able to change a method from interpreted to compiled in the middle of its execution?

I think it can.

The task is not easy for the engine (I collected some experience in that field when working on an Ahead-of-Time compiler called [JUMP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jump/) for the PalmOS handhelds years ago). When the engine decides to switch, it must consider the following points, at least:

- Where is the program counter? In interpreted code, it's at some bytecode offset from the beginning of the method, knowing exactly which bytecode to execute next. In optimized native code, typically the JVM bytecodes don't translate to isolated blocks of machine instructions, but are dependent on one another, rearranged out-of order and so on. So there might not be a native instruction address that exactly corresponds to the bytecode program counter when switching.
- Where are the data? The interpreter (probably) keeps everything on the stack, optimized native code uses a mixture of register and stack allocation that will be different for different places in the native translation.

So I read [the HotSpot whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html). It doesn't answer the question explicitly, but there's a hint under "deoptimization". When a new class is loaded dynamically or even replaced inside a debugging session, previous optimizations like inlining can become invalid.

> Therefore the Java HotSpot VM must be able to dynamically deoptimize
>   (and then reoptimize, if necessary) previously optimized hot spots,
>   even while executing code for the hot spot.

This is also switching between compiled and interpreted code, only the other way round. As this is documented behaviour of the HotSpot engine, I come to the conclusion that the switch from interpreted to compiled code within a currently executing method call is possible.

EDIT:

I wasn't explicit enough about what I understood as being the core of the question.

I understood there's a method doing a loop with 10000 iterations as follows:

```
void loop() {
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        // example loop body
        objects[i].doSomething();
    }
}
```

After e.g. 4000 iterations the HotSpot compiler has optimized that method. What happens then?

There are two aspects, one trivial and one complex:

- The trivial one is that calls that happen inside the loop (e.g. `doSomething()`) will call their compiled version as soon as it's available. I didn't mention this in my original answer as I took that for granted.
- The complex aspect is: will the currently-running `loop()` execution switch from interpreted to compiled code at i=4000? That's what I understood to be the OP's question.

Comment: Let's **not** restate the question. Let's answer the quetsion that was asked. If you have your own question, ask it, and if you have your own answer to your own question, post it there. Stick to the point.

Comment: But what happens when this method is invoked next time?